# Examples of Ruby on rails + aws congnito

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, amazon-cognito

I am building a `rails 5` app that is deployed on `heroku`.
I want to use `AWS congnito` to achieve single sign on, but there are not enough example to implement it.
I am using `devise` for authentication. Now my goal is to put my all users on `AWS cognito` and authenticate them from my rails App.

This is the only resource i found on [AWS congnito with rails](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentity/Client.html), I am looking for some example application or a link to tools or ruby API document to achieve this.

Please Help.

> Update On basis Of Bala Answer

```
require 'aws-sdk'

ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'XXXX+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
region_name = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

client = Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(
  region: region_name
)


resp = client.admin_create_user({
  user_pool_id: "us-east-1_iD7xNHj0x", # required
  username: "Test", # required
  user_attributes: [
    {
      name: "email", # required
      value: "sachin.singh@example.com",
    },
  ],
  validation_data: [
    {
      name: "Email", # required
      value: "AttributeValueType",
    },
  ],
  temporary_password: "PasswordType",
  force_alias_creation: false,
  message_action: "RESEND", # accepts RESEND, SUPPRESS
  desired_delivery_mediums: ["EMAIL"], # accepts SMS, EMAIL
})
```

> Error stack trace

```
home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.38/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': User does not exist. (Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Errors::UserNotFoundException)
    from /home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.38/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:18:in `call'
    from /home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.38/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.38/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
    from /home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.38/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.38/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from aws_cognito.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

> Update 2

```
resp = client.admin_initiate_auth({
  user_pool_id: "us-east-1_uKM", # required
  client_id: "3g766413826eul9kre28qne4f", # required
  auth_flow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
  auth_parameters: {
    "EMAIL" => "kapil.sachdev@metacube.com",
    "PASSWORD" => "Ibms#1234"
  }
})
```

Comment: I doubt you will find more example here than on google.com.

Comment: @Sachin Singh, I'm doing exactly the same thing so thank you for sharing. Did you uninstall Devise or did you hook that up inside Devise. If you kept it where does this code live?

Comment: I did not removed devise, but I stopped using most of its components, and created my own sign up, signin, forgot password controller, and business logic, in near future I will remove devise too.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Did you use a filter to validate if the user is logged in or not in each controller? I would really appreciate it if you could share whatever you can. As you mentioned there are no examples out there at all.

Comment: I used devise filter to check current_user, I suggest you to use the devise sign_in method inside your custom controllers action which will create session for user as per devise.

Comment: **Simple Solution** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054690/how-to-register-a-new-user-using-aws-cognito-ruby-sdk/64061180#64061180

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a user pool for your application

Use this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/create-new-user-pool-console-quickstart.html%20to%20create%20a%20user%20pool%20using%20the%20console.) to create user pool through AWS console

You can find the ruby methods for sign_up, sign_in,  change password and many other functions at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html

**EDIT**

Now, you can sign up the user using [sign_up](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html#sign_up-instance_method)

sign_in a user using 
[admin_initiate_auth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html#admin_initiate_auth-instance_method)

if you need mobile number confirmation, email confirmation you need to configure the user pool that you are creating.

You can find the corresponding methods for confirming the mobile numbers using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html#confirm_sign_up-instance_method

Comment: updated post, please help me with issue got while signing up new user.

Comment: @SachinSingh I have made some changes in my answer for sign up.

Comment: how can i use email/phone to authenticate instead of username?

Comment: Username is a mandatory one in AWS Cognito. 
Using Aliases to Simplify User Sign-Up and Sign-In(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html), you can sign in with email or phone number.
So while sending the sign-up request you can send the username as email.

Comment: thanks Bala but in my case for a user email and and phone both can exist at the same time and he should have a choice of using email/phone for authentication.

Comment: you can have phone_number and email as alias attributes. So in the sign in request you can send any one of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131031/discussion-between-bala-karthik-and-sachin-singh).