# How to register a new user using AWS Cognito Ruby SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I would like to know how to register a new user using AWS Cognito Ruby SDK.

So far I have tried:

**Input**

```
AWS_KEY = "MY_AWS_KEY"
AWS_SECRET = "MY_AWS_SECRET"

client = Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(
  access_key_id: AWS_KEY,
  secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET,
  region: 'us-east-1',
)

resp = client.sign_up({
  client_id: "4d2c7274mc1bk4e9fr******", # required
  username: "test@test.com", # required
  password: "Password23sing", # required
  user_attributes: [
    {
      name: "app", # required
      value: "my app name",
    },
  ],
  validation_data: [
    {
      name: "username", # required
      value: "true",
    },
  ]
})
```

**Output**

```
Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Errors::NotAuthorizedException (Unable to verify secret hash for client 4d2c7274mc1bk4e9fr*****)
```

**References**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html#sign_up-instance_method

Comment: Thanks @rmlockerd however there are many ways of setting credentials. 
I used the documentation at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html#aws-ruby-sdk-credentials-client
The client instance seems to be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your app client is configured with a client secret, most of the client requests require you to include a 'secret hash' in the options parameters of the request. The [Cognito docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#cognito-user-pools-computing-secret-hash) describe the secret hash thusly:

> The SecretHash value is a Base 64-encoded keyed-hash message
> authentication code (HMAC) calculated using the secret key of a user
> pool client and username plus the client ID in the message. The following pseudocode shows how this value is calculated.
>
> Base64 ( HMAC_SHA256 ( "Client Secret Key", "Username" + "Client Id" ) )

The docs also make it clear via a glob of sample Java that you are expected to roll your own. After a bit of experimenting I was able to successfully complete a `sign_up` call with the following (my test pool was set up to require email and name attributes):

```rb
def secret_hash(client_secret, username, client_id)
  Base64.strict_encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', CLIENT_SECRET, username + CLIENT_ID))
end

client = Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(
  access_key_id: AWS_KEY,
  secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET,
  region: REGION)

username = 'bob.scum@example.com'
resp = client.sign_up({
         client_id: CLIENT_ID,
         username: username,
         password: 'Password23sing!',
         secret_hash: secret_hash(CLIENT_SECRET, username, CLIENT_ID),
         user_attributes: [{ name: 'email', value: username },
                           { name: 'name', value: 'Bob' }],
         validation_data: [{ name: 'username', value: 'true' },
                           { name: 'email', value: 'true' }]
       })
```

`CLIENT_SECRET` is the app client secret that can be found under **General Settings > App Clients**.

Result:

```
#<struct Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Types::SignUpResponse
 user_confirmed=false,
 code_delivery_details=nil,
 user_sub="c87c2ac8-1480-4d15-a28d-6998d9260e73">
```